# What is the performance overhead of Apache ActiveMQ vs. raw sockets?

Tags: network-programming, jms, message-queue, messaging, activemq-classic

We're looking to implement ActiveMQ to handle messaging between two of our servers, over a geographically diverse environment (Australia to the UK and back, via the internet).

I've been looking for some vague indicators of performance round the net but so far have had no luck.

My question: compared to a DIY TCP/SSL implementation of basic messaging, how would ActiveMQ perform? Similar systems of our own can send and receive messages across Australia in 100-150ms, over a SSL layer with an already established connection.

Also, does ActiveMQ persist its TLS/SSL connections, thus saving a substantial amount of time that would already be used in connection creation/teardown?

What I am hoping is that it will at least perform better than HTTPS, at a per-request level.

I am aware that performance can vary remarkably, depending on hardware, networks, code and so on. I'm just after something to start with.

I know the above is a little fuzzy - if you need any clarification please let me know and I will only be too happy to oblige.

Thank you.

Comment: The comparison is so board as to be completely useless.  Each is its own domain.

Comment: @TimBish if you would be so kind as to explain why the question is useless? I see you work on MQ so I imagine you'd have some idea. Knowing if MQ persists its SSL connections would go a great way to understanding if its the right choice of technology for our problem. Is there some way I can clarify my answer? Perhaps by specifying message content size (a few K) and the speed it has to perform under (1000ms)?

Answer (score 3):

What Tim means is that this is not an apples to apples comparison. If you are solely concerned with the performance of a single point to point connection to transfer data, a direct link will give you a good result (although DIY is still a dubious design decision). If you are building a system that requires the transfer of data and you have more complex functional requirements, then a broker-based messaging platform like ActiveMQ will come into play.

You should consider broker-based messaging if you want:

- a post-office style system where a producer sends a message, and knows that it will be consumed at some point, even if there is no consumer there at that time
- to not care where the consumer of a message is, or how many of them there are
- a guarantee that a message will be consumed, even if the consumer that first handle it dies mid-way through the process (transactions, redelivery)
- many consumers, with a guarantee that a message will only be consumed once - queues
- many consumers that will each react to a single message - topics

These patterns are pretty standard, and apply to all off the shelf messaging products. As a general rule, DIY in this domain is a bad idea, as messaging is complex (see http://www.ohloh.net/p/activemq/estimated_cost for an estimate of how long it would take you do do same); and has many existing implementations of various flavours (some without a broker) that are all well used, commercially supported and don't require you to maintain them. I would think very hard before going down to the TCP level for any sort of data transfer as there is so much prior art.